# How do I get a unique username into a label based on whoever is logged in?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For some reason, the username label shows 'Bob' everytime, I think because in the console this is retrieving all data from my collection in my Firebase Firestore Database.

I want it to grab the username of the user logged in.

One thing to bear in mind also, is that my collection is called 'users' and each document is created with a unique user id everytime an account is made.

RELEVANT CODE IN ACCOUNT CLASS:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
  @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!

func checkWhichUserIsLoggedIn() {

         db.collection("users").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")


                    self.usernameLabel.text = document.data()["username"] as? String
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

CONSOLE:

```
Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
1jpE5tTwg8O0LsfL6eNW => ["uid": 72KzUt7xPsYsfS1zrFnBjNkZ0TK2, "emailAddress": billy123@gmail.com, "username": billy, "password": billy123*]
fZmd6uDKnLIknhNdYBgs => ["uid": AErBkJHexcZOHqg8RAOUA33IAQ03, "emailAddress": angie@gmail.com, "username": angie, "password": angie123*]
nthbdkzm8WdiRjt2Sakf => ["uid": OSqkxWznCxOYP87nBZlw5ieZlHC2, "emailAddress": bob@gmail.com, "username": Bob, "password": bobby123*]
```

Comment: possibly because you are trying to update UI on background thread? Try to wrap `self.usernameLabel.text = ...` in `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Comment: Tried this @KirilS. unfortunately it didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the name of the signed in user, you only need to load their document (and not all documents in he collection)

```
func checkWhichUserIsLoggedIn() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser.uid
    let docRef = db.collection("users").document(uid)

    docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")

            self.usernameLabel.text = document.data()["username"] as? String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I receive in the console when inputting your code. The problem seems to be that this is the users uid which is coming up, but the users uid is different to the document ID in firebase, which for some reason is returning me nil, not sure how to fix this. [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
Optional("AErBkJHexcZOHqg8RAOUA33IAQ03") => nil

Comment: That looks correct to me, as now you're only getting a single document. What's the remaining problem?

Comment: The problem now is that the value being returned is 'nil' meaning the label is empty, unfortunately it's not returning the username of the uid.

Comment: That part of the code is copied from your question. You might want to run the code in a debugger, and see what's happening on this line `document.data()["username"] as? String`. For example, `document` here is likely a `DocumentSnapshot?`, while in your original context it was a `DocumentSnapshot`. So you may have to convert it to a non-optional first.

Comment: Yes, on both the print line and the line where I am trying to make the label the user's name are both 'document?' (they're both optional because it would not build the application without them being optional) ... regardless of that, the value being returned is nil, which is not what should happen.